# fill Nan based on range of values in a column

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have some data in a column read from a csv file using pandas. It consists of values ranging between -1[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tseLd.jpg)1520 to +2000. I want to fill Nan, if the value is less than +550 and greater than +1800. How can I do This.

Comment: Hello to SO! Could you please show what you have done so far the solve _your_ problem? SO isn't a tutorial replacement. You need to show some effort and then pose questions related to _your_ code. Also, providing an MRE helps users to create answers ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
df.replace(df.loc[(df['Sensor_data(N)']<550) or (df['Sensor_data(N)']>1800)],'NaN',inplace=True)
```

feel free to ask if any doubt